# Combining two tables with a set of conditions in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables (doctor, clinic_doctor_timings, hosptial_doctor_timings). Both the timings table contains the id of the doctor table as foreign key and it also stores the from and to timings for the doctor. Now i need to select the doctor id who goes to the clinic or hospital in a given time i.e. from and to.

I have written a query which works either for clinic or hospital, but not both.

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
`doctor`.`id`,
`doctor`.`name`
FROM
`doctor`
JOIN clinic_doctor_timings AS cl
ON cl.doctor_id = doctor.id
WHERE
TIME_FORMAT(`cl`.`from`, %h:%i %p) >= '05:00 AM'
AND TIME_FORMAT(`cl`.`to`, %h:%i %p) >= '10:00 PM'
```

The above query works fine, but after i want to combine both the clinic_doctor_timings and hospital_doctor_timings table i do not get the results i expect.

```
.........
JOIN clinic_doctor_timings AS cl
ON cl.doctor_id = doctor.id
JOIN hospital_doctor_timings AS hs
ON hs.doctor_id = doctor.id
WHERE
(TIME_FORMAT(`cl`.`from`, %h:%i %p) >= '05:00 AM'
AND TIME_FORMAT(`cl`.`to`, %h:%i %p) <= '10:00 PM')
XOR
(TIME_FORMAT(`hs`.`from`, %h:%i %p) >= '05:00 AM'
AND TIME_FORMAT(`hs`.`to`, %h:%i %p) <= '10:00 PM')
```

i need to get both clinic and hospital for the doctor with the given timings independent of clinic and hospital.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the doctors who go to clinic:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name FROM doctor a 
INNER JOIN clinic_doctor_timings b ON a.id = b.doctor_id
WHERE 
b.`from` >= '2013-05-02 05:00:00' AND
b.`to` <= '2013-05-02 22:00:00';
```

Get the doctors who go to hospital:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name FROM doctor a 
INNER JOIN hospital_doctor_timings b ON a.id = b.doctor_id
WHERE 
b.`from` >= '2013-05-02 05:00:00' AND
b.`to` <= '2013-05-02 22:00:00';
```

Get the doctors who go to clinic and hospital

```
SELECT a.id, a.name FROM doctor a 
INNER JOIN clinic_doctor_timings b ON a.id = b.doctor_id
INNER JOIN hospital_doctor_timings c ON a.id = c.doctor_id
WHERE 
b.`from` >= '2013-05-02 05:00:00' AND
b.`to` <= '2013-05-02 22:00:00' AND
c.`from` >= '2013-05-02 05:00:00' AND
c.`to` <= '2013-05-02 22:00:00';
```

Get the doctors who go to clinic **OR** hospital

```
SELECT a.id, a.name FROM doctor a 
WHERE
(
    SELECT COUNT(b.id) FROM clinic_doctor_timings b WHERE
    b.doctor_id = a.id and
    b.`from` >= '2013-05-02 05:00:00' AND
    b.`to` <= '2013-05-02 22:00:00'
) > 0
or
(
    SELECT COUNT(c.id) FROM hospital_doctor_timings c WHERE
    c.doctor_id = a.id and
    c.`from` >= '2013-05-02 05:00:00' AND
    c.`to` <= '2013-05-02 22:00:00'
) > 0;
```

Isn't this enough to get what you want?

Comment: actually no. The third query does not get the result i expect. It only bring's the results common to both clinic and hospital. But thanks anyway. I figured a way to find it.

Comment: @Tamil I still don't understand what you want. Because your description is not clear. I am just guessing what you want.

Comment: @Tamil Ok, I have written the 4th query. Updated in my question.

Comment: Actually the code you gave is the code that i said i figured out. any way thanks for doing it. I will vote you up.